# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDl

Tags: asp.net, service

In my ASP.NET website I am trying to comsume a webserice and I and getting the following error:
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://usaepay.com/soap/gate/3213EA2A/usaepay.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://usaepay.com/soap/gate/3213EA2A/usaepay.wsdl"

Any idea on how to resolve it.

Thanks,
Pinaz.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate for the host is for www.usapay.com.  If you change your soap call to point at https://www.usaepay.com/soap/gate/3213EA2A/usaepay.wsdl your call should work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because there is an HTTPS error on the WSDL?